# How to get FunctionType from CallInst when call is indirect in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

If a function call is direct, you can get the Function type through the following code.

```
Function  * fun  = callInst->getCalledFunction();
Function  * funType = fun->getFunctionType();
```

However, if the call is indirect, that is, through a function pointer, the `getCalledFunction`
returns NULL. So my question is how to get the Function type when a function is called through a function pointer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the type from an indirect call, use `getCalledValue` instead of `getCalledFunction`, like so:

```
Type* t = callInst->getCalledValue()->getType();
```

That would get you the type of the pointer passed to the call instruction; to get the actual function type, continue with:

```
FunctionType* ft = cast<FunctionType>(cast<PointerType>(t)->getElementType());
```

Comment: Thanks for such a good answer. I guess, Type* would be enough for casting the void* pointer to the function pointer, because we need to use BitCastInst for that purpose I think, and that class happens to take Type* as its parameter.

Comment: @MetallicPriest yes, casting to `t` is what you need to do with an arbitrary pointer to make it conform to your `callInst`. I think you mean `i8*`, however, and not `void*`, which is not a legal LLVM type.

Comment: I am trying to get the name of the function of an indirect call: 'Value* v = CI->getCalledValue();  Value* sv = v->stripPointerCasts();  StringRef fname = sv->getName();' But doesn't really work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nice and informative answer by Oak.

As per recent versions of LLVM, `getFunctionType` of the [CallBase](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html) class can be used.